# How to transform a vec3 by a mat4?

Tags: javascript, c++, directx

I'm translating a bit of code into javascript. I'm trying to replicate the functionality of

```
 D3DXVECTOR3* D3DXVec3TransformCoord(
 __inout  D3DXVECTOR3 *pOut,
 __in     const D3DXVECTOR3 *pV,
 __in     const D3DXMATRIX *pM
 );
```

This applies Mat4 transformation to the Vec3 (which would lead to an invalid mat4). How do I project the 4d matrix into the 3d matrix and perform the operation? In what order would you do the math? We can assume that W=1, as in the following post:

[DirectX Math function confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650570/directx-math-function-confusion)

Comment: Are you really asking how to transform a matrix by a vector?

Comment: Look here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/11906-d3dxvec3transformcoord/

Comment: Well, between built in c++ and D3DXVec3Transform and D3DXVec3TransformCoord, I just want to be certain about what exact math they perform. You never know if its doing a little more or a little less than you expect based on a name. That link helps. Now I know where to find the internals.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13690070/6908282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this function says "*Transforms a 3D vector by a given matrix, projecting the result back into w = 1*".

In other words the function extends the vector *[x,y,z]* to *[x,y,z,1]* and then performs the multiplication, truncating the result to three elements after the operation.

EDIT: According to [this thread](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/599746-question-about-d3dxvec3transformcoord/) the operation is *xA*, i.e multiplication with a row vector on the left, which is equivalent to the homogeneous transformation: *xM(0) + yM(1) + zM(2) + M(3)*, where *M(i)* is the i'th column of the matrix.

Comment: Is this the same as normal c++ Vec3 * Mat4? I see that operator getting used, but I wonder what it's actually doing.

Comment: Mathematically Vec3 * Mat4 is not defined, the vector length has to match the number of rows in the matrix. If you take the w=1 "projection" into account then you should get the same result as a Vec4 * Mat4 routine.

Answer (score 0):

Other than building it yourself you can also use an existing npm package called [`gl-matrix`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gl-matrix) which has a [`transformMat4`](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix/blob/master/src/vec3.js#L505) function in the `vec3.js` module of the package.

OR

you can use the [below function](https://gist.github.com/AnweshGangula/3f3d0d7f28464ea658c28d3ce35cbf6e#file-vec3-mat4-py-L58) to do the transformation yourself

```js
function transformMat4AG(out, a, m) {
    var x = a[0],
        y = a[1],
        z = a[2];
    var w = m[3] * x + m[7] * y + m[11] * z + m[15];
    w = w || 1.0;
    out[0] = (m[0] * x + m[4] * y + m[8] * z + m[12]) / w;
    out[1] = (m[1] * x + m[5] * y + m[9] * z + m[13]) / w;
    out[2] = (m[2] * x + m[6] * y + m[10] * z + m[14]) / w;
    return out;
}
```