# How can I transform a glm::vec3 by a glm::mat4

Tags: opengl, transform, glm-math

I want to transform a `glm::vec3` (camera.target) by a `glm::mat4` (camera.rotationMatrix). I try multiply this give me an error:error: no match for 'operator*' in 'originalTarget * `((Camera*)this)->Camera::rotationMatrix`. I suppose that I can't multiply a vec3 * mat4.
Does GLM some function to transform this? Other way to do the transform?

The code:

```
void Camera::Update(void)
{
// Aplicamos la rotacion sobre el target
glm::vec3 originalTarget = target;
glm::vec3 rotatedTarget = originalTarget * rotationMatrix;

// Aplicamos la rotacion sobre el Up
glm::vec3 originalUp = up;
glm::vec3 rotatedUp = originalUp * rotationMatrix;

// Establecemos las matrices de vista y proyeccion
view = lookAt(
position, //eye
rotatedTarget, //direction
rotatedUp //up
);
projection = perspective(
FOV,
(float) getParent()->getEngine()->GetCurrentWidth() / getParent()->getEngine()->GetCurrentWidth() ,
near_plane,
far_plane);
}
```

Comment: Check out the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74501722/6908282) to see how its done in JavaScript

Answer (score 17):

You want to first convert your `glm::vec3` into a `glm::vec4` with the 4th element a `0`, and then multiply them together.

```
glm::vec4 v(originalUp, 0);
```

Comment: Guess you meant "with the 4th element equals 1.0", no? Translate transfroms won't work with 0.

Comment: Since it's the up vector for the camera, it does not need to be translated, so a zero is more appropriate in this case